# how to use mysql query in yii framework

Tags: yii

I am new to yii framework using yii 1.1.14 First of all I didnt understand it. My target is to insert, select, update and delete data from database . Its  very confusing for me.please give me some example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some examples

1.Insert query in YII2

$connection = Yii::$app->db;

$connection->createCommand()->insert('tbl_name', [

```
        'column1' => Yii::$app->request->post('column1'),

        'column2' => Yii::$app->request->post('column2'),   

        ])->execute();
```

2.Update query

Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('tbl_name',  [

```
        'column1' => Yii::$app->request->post('column1'),

        'column2' => Yii::$app->request->post('column2'),   
    ],
        'where_id ="'.$where.'" ')->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommended you to use Gii, and use it to generate a Model of table.

For example, table: user(columns: id,name), Model: User.

You can insert or update data like the following:

```
$user = new User(); // Insert
// $user = User::find()->where(['id'=>'1'])->one(); // Update
$user->name = "Insert data";
$user->save();
```

See also http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html

Answer (score 0):

For the queries you can use **[Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar)** and for **CRUD** you can use **[Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii)**